# How to get difference between two days in iPhone

Tags: iphone, c, date

I would like to calculate the no of days,hours,minutes between two different dates in iPhone(Objective C). Please provide any code sample to do the same.

Thanks 
Sandeep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dates are in NSDate objects, you can use the timeIntervalSinceDate method to find the difference as an NSTimeInterval, which will give you the difference in seconds.

You can then convert seconds to days, hours and minutes via a simple algorithm (this is off the top of my head and not tested):

```
minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds %= 60;
hours = minutes / 60;
minutes %= 60;
days = hours / 24;
hours %= 24;
```

Comment: Thanks Ferruccio this was the exact thing I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    unsigned int uintFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* differenceComponents = [gregorian components:uintFlags fromDate:firstDate toDate:secondDate options:0];
```

then just check properties of differenceComponents. You can find all these properties in the documentation provided with XCode

Comment: +1 for "documentation provided with Xcode" - it's also available on Apple's dev website: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCEGJCC

Answer (score 2):

I have written a comprehensive program to give the difference between two dates in C (dont know this is what you mean by Objective C). Please find the original work here.

http://tech.bragboy.com/2010/02/different-between-two-days-implemented.html

Answer (score 0):

Building off Ferruccio's answer, something like this will get you from finding the time difference to a concatenated string where you can tell how many days, hours and minutes from the date you're comparing (YOURNSDATE) till now

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:YOURNSDATE];
        NSInteger seconds = (NSInteger)timeDifference;
        NSInteger minutes;
        NSInteger hours;
        NSInteger days;

        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds %= 60;
        hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes %= 60;
        days = hours / 24;
        hours %= 24;

        NSString* daysString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i days ", days];
        if(days == 0){
            daysString = @"";
        }else if(days == 1){
            daysString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i day ", days];
        }
        NSString* hoursString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i hrs ", hours];
        if(hours == 0){
            hoursString = @"";
        }else if(hours == 1){
            hoursString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i hr ", hours];
        }
        NSString* minutesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i min", minutes];
        if(minutes == 0){
            minutesString = @"";
        }

        NSString *AllDatesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", daysString, hoursString, minutesString];
```